# Dockerfile run locally has google cloud SDK, same Dockerfile in production does not

Tags: docker, google-cloud-sdk

Our Dockerfile has the following lines:

```
# Installing google cloud SDK for gsutil
RUN apt-get update && \
    echo "deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/cloud.google.gpg] http://packages.cloud.google.com/apt cloud-sdk main" | tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-cloud-sdk.list && \
    curl https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | apt-key --keyring /usr/share/keyrings/cloud.google.gpg  add - && \
    apt-get update -y && \
    apt-get install google-cloud-sdk -y
```

When we launch a docker container locally from this image, and `docker exec -it containerID bash` into the container, we get:

```
airflow@containerID:~$ gsutil --version
gsutil version: 4.65
```

When we launch a docker container on our GCP compute engine from this image, and `docker exec -it containerID bash` into the container, we get:

```
airflow@containerID:~$ gsutil --version
bash: gsutil: command not found
```

I thought the whole point of docker and dockerfiles was so that we could avoid this exact issue of something working locally but not in production... We're at a loss for how to even debug this?

Comment: Hi there! [qq] Are you sure that both containers are using exactly the same image with the same hash? You are totally right, the idea of using Docker is to avoid this kind of situation so I think that the issue may be with the image that maybe they are slightly different. I have never seen an issue like this before.

Comment: Rebuilding the image seems to have done the trick. I dont change this dockerfile often - perhaps it was changed a few weeks back, rebuilt locally but not rebuilt on prod

Comment: Could you please provide a detailed answer on how you solved the issue?

Comment: i ran `docker-compose build` to rebuild the docker-image.